# Send POST request over Mobile Data

Tags: android, python, pythonanywhere

I am developing an Android app that sends and receives data from a python server hosted in **pythonanywhere** using HTTP requests and JSON.

The application is working perfect via WIFI but the problem occurs when I use it via Mobile Data. All the data coming from server with GET requests works perfectly but POST and DELETE request do not appear to send or otherwise work.

I don't know whether the problem is

1. free server
2. untrusted app
3. permissions

***PostRequest.java***

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public abstract class PostRequest extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {


    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }   

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        InputStream inputstream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(params[1]);
            post.setEntity(se);
            post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(post);
            inputstream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            if(inputstream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputstream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("[ error stream ]", e.toString());
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    abstract public void onPostExecute(String result);

}
```

***RequestAddNewStory.java***

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.shortstory.activities.AddHashtag;
import com.shortstory.api.PostRequest;

public class RequestAddNewStory extends PostRequest {

    Context context ;
    Button AddHashtag ;

    public RequestAddNewStory(Context context , Button AddHashtag)
    {
        this.context = context ;
        this.AddHashtag = AddHashtag ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {

        JSONObject json;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(result);
            String s = json.getString("message");
            if (s.equals("done")) {

               Toast.makeText(context,"now add hashtags", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               Intent Addhashtag = new Intent(context , AddHashtag.class);
               context.startActivity(Addhashtag);
               ((Activity) context).finish();
            }else
            {
                AddHashtag.setEnabled(true);
                Toast.makeText(context,"can't add story", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

***when request send***

```
json.accumulate("user_name", "mkm");
json.accumulate("title", "hello");
json.accumulate("body", "hello all");
json.accumulate("img", " ");
RequestAddNewStory rans = new RequestAddNewStory(this , AddHashtag);
rans.execute("http://-----.pythonanywhere.com/api/story" , json.toString());
```

Comment: Mobile data can be slow so you can handle it with `connection timeout`, for more help show your code...

Comment: thank you , i will post some code now

Comment: I post some code now @hrskrs

Comment: maybe the authentication failed for your post/delete requests?

Comment: i don't know , there is a solution for that @conrad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 3 weeks of debugging and see log files of server and log cat of client I'm not found any logical error happens so i return to see **pythonanywhere** free server limitations I found :

***Access to external internet sites from your code e.g. urllib or wget***

***Specific sites via HTTP(S) only***

i don't know what is point means but i decided use **https** instead of **http** and it's work perfect in both wifi and mobile data

```
json.accumulate("user_name", "mkm");
json.accumulate("title", "hello");
json.accumulate("body", "hello all");
json.accumulate("img", " ");
RequestAddNewStory rans = new RequestAddNewStory(this , AddHashtag);
rans.execute("https://-----.pythonanywhere.com/api/story" , json.toString());
```

But i'm still don't know if **pythonanywhere** free server allow you to send your requests only **https** why **http** request work perfect via wifi only.

Comment: just to clarify, the pythonanywhere whitelist limits what external sites a free account can access (eg: google.com etc) and has nothing to do with http/https

Comment: but requests not work in http and work perfect with https  I'm not found any explanation for that @conrad